# How to construct widget programmatically with style applied

Tags: resources, styles, xamarin.android, xamarin

To create for instance a button you can use the constructor:

```cs
new Android.Widget.Button(MyActivity.Window.Context);
```

But if you want to do that and apply styling you need to use:

```cs
new Android.Widget.Button(MyActivity.Window.Context, AttrSet);
```

where the AttrSet is an AttributeSet for the styling.

I have defined a style for my button in Resources/values/styles.xml and I then want to apply the style to the button in the constructor. I know following is not working:

```cs
System.Xml.XmlReader XmlRdr = MyActivity.Resources.GetXml(Resource.Style.MyButtonStyle);
var AttrSet = Android.Util.Xml.AsAttributeSet(XmlRdr);
Android.Widget.Button MyButton = new Android.Widget.Button(MyActivity.Window.Context,AttrSet);
```

But how can I then construct my button and apply a style from my resources in a way similar to the above?

Comment: Have you found a solution?